# C++ using a block of code multiple times in the main code

Tags: c++

I need something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int x;
x=0;
SOMETHING{
    cout << "Something has been done" << endl;
    x++;
}
do SOMETHING;
return 0;
}
```

I want to define a block of code that will be repeated in the main code a lot of times, but not in a loop. I don't want a function, I just want to define a part of code that will repeat a lot of times later and that I can simply call with one line (that part of code need to be able to operate with integers/arrays in the main code).
Can someone help me?

This is a program for solving the Rubik's cube. It looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int front[10], back[10], left[10], right[10], top[10], bottom[10];
    int frontP[10], backP[10], leftP[10], rightP[10], topP[10], bottomP[10];
    /* Assuming the data has been inputed */

    /* Move Top Clockwise - U */
    left[1]=frontP[1];left[2]=frontP[2];left[3]=frontP[3];
    back[1]=leftP[1];back[2]=leftP[2];back[3]=leftP[3];
    right[1]=backP[1];right[2]=backP[2];right[3]=backP[3];
    front[1]=rightP[1];front[2]=rightP[2];front[3]=rightP[3];
    top[1]=topP[7];top[2]=topP[4];top[3]=topP[1];top[4]=topP[8];top[6]=topP[2];top[7]=topP[9];top[8]=topP[6];top[9]=topP[3];
    for (int i=1;i<=9;i++){
        topP[i]=top[i];leftP[i]=left[i];rightP[i]=right[i];backP[i]=back[i];frontP[i]=front[i];
    }
}
```

There are 12 arrays representing 2 states of the cube (one before the move has been made, and one helping state to make the move possible - just to switch color around). The "Move Top Clockwise" function just switches the colors around and then evens out the arrays and gives the solving string letter "U". There are 12 possible moves and the complete algorithm should find the shortest string that solves the rubiks cube (for example "RL'DUB'").
My program isn't really for solving the Rubik's cube, but this example helped in explaining my problem.

Comment: That sounds a lot like a function to me.

Comment: Oliver is right a function will fit this perfectly

Comment: Can you show a real example of what this block of code would be, and why it can't be done with a function?

Comment: Actually, it also sounds like `for (auto i = 0ull; i < 2; ++i)`

Comment: The actual use of this is pretty complicated, but I'll expand the question and try to explain it...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use functions, use *lamdas* starting with C++11.

Lambdas are basically anonymous functions, which I think is what you want, you seem to not want to define be a separate function:

```
auto something = [&x]() {
    std::cout << "Something had been done\n";
    ++x;
};
```

Then, you can call it:

```
something();
```